# String Value Try Catch in Vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, declaration, definition, declare

I am having a hard time understanding why this always returns an empty variable

```
    Private Function checkEnvelopeStatus(aEnvelopeID As String) As String
    Dim lEnvelopeStatusMessage As String

    Try
        Dim lEnvelopeStatus = mDsapi.RequestStatusEx(aEnvelopeID)
        lEnvelopeStatusMessage = "Subject:" & lEnvelopeStatus.Subject & vbCrLf & "Status Code: " & lEnvelopeStatus.Status
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace, ex.Message)
    End Try

    Return lEnvelopeStatusMessage
End Function
```

Yet this will return the message I want

```
    Private Function checkEnvelopeStatus(aEnvelopeID As String) As String
    Dim lEnvelopeStatusMessage As String

    Try
        Dim lEnvelopeStatus = mDsapi.RequestStatusEx(aEnvelopeID)
        aEnvelopeID = "Subject:" & lEnvelopeStatus.Subject & vbCrLf & "Status Code: " & lEnvelopeStatus.Status
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace, ex.Message)
    End Try

    Return aEnvelopeID 
End Function
```

It seems that the value of the string when it is a variable local to the function is being cleared out after my TRy catch closes. Yet when I replace it with the parameter coming in I am able to preserve the string external to the Try Catch? I am mainly a C#/C++ developer so this is confusing behavior for me. Can anyone explain why this might happen?

Here is a much more sanitized version of the code above

```
Public Function foo(a As String) As String
    Dim b As String
    Try
        b = "banana:"
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    Return b
End Function
```

It exhibits the same behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C#, you cannot compile a method's code where a path exist, in the execution flow, that could lead to the exit from the method without initializing the return value. You get a compiler error for using a variable not assigned.

In VB.NET you would have avoided the error if you had changed the option 
**"Use of variable before assignement"** from **Warning** to **Error** in the Build page of your project options. (And I strongly recommend to do so)

(Not sure for the exact name of the option because I use a localized version of Visual Studio)

Answer (score 1):

That code should not compile,I tried this, and it gave me a compiler error "Error  3  Use of unassigned local variable 'b'"

Something wrong with your compiler, what are you using?

```
    static public string foo(string a)
    {
        String b;
        try
        {
            b = "banana";
        }
        catch
        {

        }

        return b;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't compile till you rethrow the excaption. Consider following:

```
public String foo(String a) {
    String b;

    try {
        b="banana:";
    }
    catch {
        throw;
    }

    return b;
}
```

This code would compile, because if there was an exception, it rethrows. 
The compiler predicts the logical problems like unreachable code(though unreachable code was not an error). Equivalence in VB.net:

```
Public Function foo(a As String) As String
    Dim b As String

    Try
        b = "banana:"
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try

    Return b
End Function
```

By the way, catch any exception was considered a bad practice of coding.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the same code in C#

```
public string foo(string a)
{
    String b;
    try
    {
        b = "banana";
    }
    catch
    {

    }

    return b;
}
```

}

It does seem to exhibit the same behavior. I was taken back. Thinking about it more, it makes sense. I am just declaring the variable not actually defining it to anything yet. So replacing the above examples with something like this:

```
        public string foo(string a)
    {
        String b = "";
        try
        {
            b = "banana";
        }
        catch
        {

        }

        return b;
    }
}
```

Fixed all my problems. Hope this can help someone in the future. The more you know....